# How to replace string values from column with NA and turn column into float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column in my dataframe which looks like this:

```
col
12
77
15
"UNKNOWN"
12
```

dtype: object

I want to replace `"UNKNOWN"` with `NA` and turn object into float type. But when I do this:

```
df["col"].replace({"UNKNOWN": np.nan}, inplace=True)
```

This error appears: `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `df["col"].replace("UNKNOWN", np.nan, inplace=True)` or `df["col"].replace({"UNKNOWN": float("nan")}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing it might be better if you use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` that will automatically turn string like values into `np.nan` and also convert your column to `numeric` type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[12,77,15,'"UNKNOWN"',12]})
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')

print(df)

    col
0  12.0
1  77.0
2  15.0
3   NaN
4  12.0
```